# Add or remove relations one-to-many entity doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many

I want add or remove relations on entity from an array of Ids.

Code example:

```
 List<int> brands // have values 1, 2, 3 

 using (ContextDB db = new ContextDB())
 {
     Industrie industrie = db.Industrie.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IndustrieId == id);
     industrie.Brand = db.Brand.Where(p => brands.Contains(p.BrandId)).ToList(); // Brand = ICollection<Brand> // relation

     db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Debugging works, but only debugging. I don't know how happened why not debugging doesn't work. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What is the error message, where it it happening, do you have a separate config for DEBUG and RELEASE ?

Comment: No error occurs, but the update only occurs with a breakpoint debugging code, but on runtime nothing

Comment: Your debugging, and even though you do the exact same actions, it doesn't end up with the same result if you remove the break point ?

Comment: exactly. thats the case

Comment: It's... i won't say impossible but... this is a very deep case...

Comment: Solved!. Thanks @AntoinePelletier

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I forgot to use in this case `.Inclure(string)`

Replace this:

```
Industrie industrie = db.Industrie.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IndustrieId == id);
```

To this:

```
Industrie industrie = db.Industrie.Include("Brand").FirstOrDefault(p => p.IndustrieId == id);
```